# Enter only number in text box by javascript onkeypress problem

Tags: javascript, string, validation, numbers, dom-events

I have a html text box,  `onkeypress` event will call a function and the function allow to enter only numbers (0-9). this is working fine when the user enter by directly.

The problem will come when the user copy and paste some character or String into the text box. I don't know when should I call that JavaScript function to validate pasted values are Number or Char.

Any idea?

Comment: @op , you should do a validation on the server anyway . Regarding your current problem , try using the onchange event .

Answer (score 2):

May be you can try use onchange event and then check with regex..

Comment: In some browsers (at least in Chrome), it isn't until you blur the textbox that it fires the `onchange` event.

Answer (score 2):

You can use one of the new HTML5 form tags, as `<input type=number" \>` or `<input type="range" />`.

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider not writing your own script here?

I do use [jQuery MaskedInput](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) and it works perfectly for this

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#textbox").change(function(){
    //validate the text here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is because you're returning false for every non-numeric input.

You can either research how to identify things like Ctrl+C, or you can switch to a blacklist approach. You really only want to disallow non-numeric printable characters, so you can probably do this with a codepoint range.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using normal Javascript, use the `object.onpaste = handler;`
e.g.

```
<html>...
    <input id="something" type="text" />
...
  <script>
    var el = document.getElementById('something');
    el.onpaste = function() {
       // do you stuff here
    } ...
```

Probably better to use `onchange`

And using a library like jQuery to do it for you is nice.

But if you want to learn the innards of javascript... do it yourself! Sometimes it's better to reinvent the wheel when learning.

Comment: @Kooilnc: No, it isn't. It's implemented in current versions of all major browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be to use `setInterval` to create your own (pseudo) change listener for form fields. See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/9ssKZ/) for an example.